# Xampp no me funciona

Tags: php

Yo se que este no es el sitio para hacer esta pregunta, pero ya los recorrí todos, averigue en todos lados y nada. En Windows 7 me sale el error 0xc000007b, el cual no me deja que Xampp conecte apache ni MySQL, por lo tanto lo que estoy programando en PHP no puedo saber si anda o no. Alguna solución o sugerencia, Gracias desde ya.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Podrias agregar mas información acerca  y poner algunas imagenes??

Comment: Ese es un error que da por lo general por la falta de archivos dll's en carpetas como System32 o SysWOW64, prueba instalando el Directx ó busca cómo solucionar dicho error para que puedas descargar todas las dlls que te puedan hacer falta. También podrías usar otro servidor local como Appserv o Wampp

Comment: Probablemente sea un tema de actualizaciones o lo que es más probable te falte por instalar algún Visual C++ Redistributable. Comprueba estos puntos. Por cierto, hasta donde yo se Directx no tiene nada que ver con XAMPP, ya que es una API multimedia, al menos no es requerida como tal.